# How to load N lines of data and assigning it to a variable using for loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a huge dataset called df(approx 16gb of data). 
Wanted to open it 100 rows at one time, and everytime it reads the 100 rows, we assign it to a variable. 
This means that the first variable should have rows between 1-100, second variable should have 101-200.

The code to load the first 100 rows of data into 10 variables should be this:

```
reportlen <- seq(10,100,10)
for (i in length(reportlen)){
  file <- fread(paste0("C:/Users/Documents/data.csv,", "nrows =",reportlen[i]))
  assign(paste0("f", i),file)
}
```

However, I ran into an error and it gave me null value.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to go with your current approach, then you would probably have to use the `skip` feature of `fread`, to offset the current read by whatever amount you have already read.

But, given that you are planning to bring the entire file into memory anyway, I recommend just reading the entire file in one go:

```
df <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/Documents/data.csv")
parts <- str(split(df, (as.numeric(rownames(df))-1) %/% 100))
```

The variable `parts` should be a list, containing multiple data frames, each of which is 100 rows in length (except possibly for the last data frame, which might have some other count).

Comment: My dataset has 73337 variables and more close to 16000 rows. Reading read.csv at one go will cause my computer to hang.

Comment: That's not really the issue here.  The issue is whether you can tolerate having the entire data set in memory, in R, at one time.  If you _can_, then my solution is probably the way to go.  Doing it your way won't make reading the entire file faster, quite the opposite, it will probably slow it down.

Comment: So I've tried using read.csv on the 10 rows of data. But it seems like reading read.csv is taking way longer as compared to using fread on 10 rows of data. So i guess that using read.csv on all my data will take way longer.

Comment: That's not a particularly good benchmark.  Comparing with 1000 rows would be more meaningful.

Comment: The difference is already very obvious at 10th row. So I believe the time difference would just be more when im loading 1000 rows

Comment: No...the thing is, there can be an initial penalty paid in setup/startup time when each function gets called.  Once you get into thousands of rows, presumably that startup time will become rounding error, and you can see the truth performance of both methods.